Using pgdump_all and cron
I have a daily cron job to dump my database. Part of the crontab includes the following:
01   01 *   *   *   root    /etc/cron.d/backupDaily.sh

and part of the backup script contains the following:
cd /data/pgsql/
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_dumpall>/data/pgsql/pg.sql

My old notes refer to putting the credentials in a file such as /.pgpass . However, I have upgraded my server a few times since the beginning, and I don’t appear to have this file anymore.
Can anybody tell me how I get away with this? Does this suggest that my postgres user doesn’t have a password?
Here is what’s in my pg_hba.conf file:
#   TYPE    DATABASE        USER    ADDRESS         METHOD
    local   replication     all                     peer
    host    replication     all     127.0.0.1/32    ident
    host    replication     all     ::1/128         ident

    local   all             all                     trust

#   IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all     127.0.0.1/32    trust
    host    all             all     192.168.0.0/24  trust
    host    all             all     192.168.1.0/24  trust
    host    all             all     192.168.77.0/24 trust


Inspect your pg_hba.conf . Can be configured differently. Often there is local peer authentication for the postgres user - that is, a password is not used, instead the name of the unix user who called pg_dumpall is checked.

@Melkij I checked that before, but I didn’t know what to look for. There is one entry which reads local replication all peer. Would that be it?

It is not unlikely that local connections are allowed without a password.

@LaurenzAlbe How would I check that?

Simple: try to connect. But your pg_hba.conf line has peer, which means that no password is requested. Look at the documentation!

Actually, that's only for replication connections. Please add all relevant lines from pg_hba.conf to the question.

@LaurenzAlbe I’ve added the configuration.

The pg_hba.conf line
local   all             all                     trust

allows local connections with trust authentication, that is, without a password. That is why your backup script is working even without a password file.
The user postgres may still have a password. As a superuser, you can see the password hash with
SELECT rolpassword
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolname = 'postgres';


".pgpass" is typically a hidden file in your user's home directory (not in the root as your notation suggests--if you refer to the fact that crontab is for the root user and runs the script as root, on most systems the home directory for root would be '/root/', or something, not '/').  Upgrading your PostgreSQL server would have nothing to do with this. It would still work on the new server just like the old one provided you didn't do anything to break it. Upgrading the OS of the server might make that file disappear, depending on how you did it.
You could test this by using the -W switch with psql, and then entering an obviously wrong password at a prompt.  If this gives you password error, then you probably do have a valid .pgpass file whether you know it or not. Or you could just run ls -a in your (root's) home directory to show even hidden files.
